# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no atrribute 'CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE'

Tags: python, opencv

I've looked all over and can't find an answer to this question, so I am going to go ahead and ask. I am trying to figure out opencv for python and I am getting stuck. Everytime I run this code it tells me there is no attribute named 'CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE'. Then I tried using every CV_CHAIN_APPROX and nothing worked. I even went to my IDLE and it didn't know what it was either, so I'm stuck. 
I am trying to make a program that will find the center cordinates of a moving target. Would using findContours be the right direction? 
Sorry! I'm new to stackoverflow, so I'm not really sure what I can ask in these questions! 
Thanks so much!!

---

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2() 

while True: 
    _, frame = cap.read() 
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame) 
    filtered = cv2.medianBlur(fgmask, 15) 
    (a, b, c) = cv2.findContours(filtered, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 

    cv2.imshow('cont', b) 
    cv2.imshow('fg', fgmask) 
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Opencv 3.0> based on `createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2`, so your line need to be like:

```
(a, b, c) = cv2.findContours(filtered, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Don't forget `cv2.` in front of every OpenCV function.

Answer (score 0):

In version '2.4.9' I can clearly see `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` (and others too) are you sure you haven't forgotten to add the `cv2.` in front of it like you did in your example. If not please add the version by doing `cv2.__version__`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I did have that in my code. I just jotted that down quickly. I know it should be there, which is why I am so confused.

Comment: @Dr.Snow What's the cv version? The code works for me once I add use my answer. Are you sure you added the `cv2.` and then removed the `CV_` from `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` because it is supposed to be `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` not `cv2.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE`